# How to stop excel from changing hex number?

Tags: excel

I have to enter hex values in a column in excel worksheet.

Now whenever I write the number 01E0, it changes it to 1.00E+00.

How do I stop this from happening?

Comment: format column as text

Answer (score 1):

Excel provides formatting and recognizes your input as a number and tries to display it correctly as a number, containing the Euler number.

In your case, the simplest approach would be to tell Excel to stop doing this, by formatting the column/field/row as text. How to do this is explained [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Format-numbers-as-text-583160db-936b-4e52-bdff-6f1863518ba4).

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you want the value to be stored as text-

```
'01E0
```

Comment: Perfect and the easiest solution! Thank you!!